# Can't access edit summary when editing a long answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, android-app, edit-summary

In Android App v1.0.35 has a bug when editing answers. This was produced on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2.

For any sufficiently short answer, the edit summary is totally visible and accessible:

> [image: provided your phone is tall enough]

However, if the answer is very long, there's no way at all to get to it - I can't scroll down to it, only to the bottom of the answer itself.

> [image: unless your phone is long enough to use for a bat]

That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this! As of version 1.0.39 the entire Ask/Edit answer page will be scrollable, if needed.